# How to use else statement in jade template?

Tags: node.js, express

New to node.js.  I've generated a simple website using express.  I've added the following text in `index.jade`:

```
raining = true
if(raining === true)    
    p It is raining. Take an umbrella!
else  
    p No rain. Take the bike!
```

When I commented out the last two statements, I get the anticipated response: *"It is raining. Take an umbrella!"*

When I include the last two lines, I get an unexpected token error:

```
Unexpected token (57:0)

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (57:0)
at Parser.pp.raise (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/acorn-globals/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:943:13)
at Parser.pp.unexpected (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/acorn-globals/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1503:8)
at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/acorn-globals/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:327:12)
at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/acorn-globals/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:216:19)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/acorn-globals/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:197:19)
at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/acorn-globals/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:151:19)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/acorn-globals/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:133:19)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/acorn-globals/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:110:19)
at Parser.pp.parseExpression (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/acorn-globals/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:86:19)
at Parser.pp.parseStatement (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/acorn-globals/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1750:23)
```

Not sure why the inclusion of the else statement could cause an error.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the actual snippet of code. It would be easier to understand where exactly the error is occuring.

Comment: This question is about an else statement in a jade template, not about an else statement in express - edited title accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

be careful with indentation:

here is an example

http://jsfiddle.net/heanfig/z8wn5qz9/

check it jade reference

http://learnjade.com/tour/conditionals/

```
- var raining = true
if raining == true
        p It is raining. Take an umbrella!
else
        p No rain. Take the bike!
```

or even:

```
| #{raining ? raining : 'man'}
```